# calling a variable in A href URL | encoding

Tags: encoding, href, urlencode, encode, idoc

I 'm sending notification mails wherein client variable in  a href URL breaks as it contains '&'.For e.g. clientname is tech & Design. When i call this variable it breaks at tech. How to resolve this?Is encoding a resolution and how do i do it?

```
        "<a href="mailto:xyz@abc.com?subject=ACTION REQUIRED: <$ClientName$> is in your workflow queue | PID: <$xProject_ID$> | DID:<$dID$> | Approve">"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regexReplaceAll function helped me resolve the issue. it replaces the matched value from variable. In my case &

Here it is  ***< $regexReplaceAll(ClientName,"&","")$>***

< a href="mailto:xyz@abc.com?subject=ACTION REQUIRED: < $regexReplaceAll(ClientName,"&","")$> is in your workflow queue | PID: < $xProject_ID$> | DID:< $dID$> | Approve">"

Answer (score 0):

Use `<$xml(ClientName)$>` instead of `<$ClientName$>`

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e10726/c08_config_ref346.htm

Comment: @Yashwanth  it didn't worked as you said. i found a function . please check my answer. Thanks